# Using Group By in more then a column in a DataTable

Tags: .net, linq, datatable

I've got a problem with a Linq Query in .net.
I've this simple table stored in a DataTable called DBToUse.
Before the query I want to excute, the table is already filtered by Primary Unit.

```
PrimaryUnit - ErrorCode - ErrorDescription - Count
    Unit3         2           axe 3 
    Unit3         1           no source
    Unit3         1           axe 1
    Unit3         1           axe 2
    Unit3         1           axe 2 
    Unit3         2           axe 3
    Unit3         3           axe 3
```

I'd like to have the following table using the clause Group By.

```
Error Code and Description - Count
    2 - axe 3                  2
    1 - axe 2                  2
    3 - axe 3                  1
    1 - axe 1                  1
    1 - no source              1
```

I made this simple query to start.

```
Dim query = From row In DBToUse.AsEnumerable()
                Select PU = DBToUse.Columns("PrimaryUnit"), C = DBToUse.Columns("Count"), EC = DBToUse.Columns("ErrorCode"), ED = DBToUse.Columns("ErrorDescription")
                Group By EC Into prova = Group
```

1 - Can anyone help me to use Group By in two columns?

2 - Why when I run the query in debug mode and I process it I get this message 'expected a type'?

thanks to everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an anonymous type, this should work:

```
Dim errorGroups = From row In DBToUse
                  Let puError = New With {
                    Key .PrimaryUnit = row.Field(Of String)("PrimaryUnit"),
                    Key .ErrorCode = row.Field(Of String)("ErrorCode"),
                    Key .ErrorDescription = row.Field(Of String)("ErrorDescription")
                  }
                  Group row By puError Into puErrorGroup = Group
                  Order By puErrorGroup.Count() Descending

Dim aggregatedTable As DataTable = DBToUse.Clone() ' empty table, same columns '
For Each grp In errorGroups
    Dim row = aggregatedTable.Rows.Add()
    row.SetField("PrimaryUnit", grp.puError.PrimaryUnit)
    row.SetField("ErrorCode", grp.puError.ErrorCode)
    row.SetField("ErrorDescription", grp.puError.ErrorDescription)
    row.SetField("Count", grp.puErrorGroup.Count())
Next
```